How to scale view3D area or scene to adjust the viewing area by scaling the X and Y axes independently for visualizing or manipulating geometries
I want to create feature/add-on for scaling viewport along with objects in scene. The viewport/View3D should be compressed or stretched by scaling x or y axis independently. This is called asymmetric scaling and is particularly useful for visualizing or manipulating geometries.
How it Works:
X and Y Axis Scaling: The feature enables you to scale the viewport along the X and Y axes using different scaling values. For example, you can stretch or compress the viewport more in the X direction (horizontal) than in the Y direction (vertical), or vice versa.
Asymmetric Scaling: This means you can apply a different scale factor to the X-axis compared to the Y-axis, creating an effect where the proportions of the viewport are changed independently along each axis. This is useful when you need to focus on specific parts of the model that might require more detailed analysis or adjustment in one direction but not the other.
Use Cases:
Distortion or Focus: If you are working with a surface or model that has more detail or variation in one axis (e.g., a long, narrow component), asymmetric scaling allows you to zoom in or stretch the view to focus on areas of interest without distorting the actual geometry of the model.
Object modifications: In design and modeling, you might want to adjust the vertices of the 3d object when distorted in one direction.

Hello, would you have an example of such feature being used, perhaps in another software ? I have trouble visualizing what you want to do.

Hello, thanks for response. The feature that I want to implement is similar to icem surf feature called scale with nonproportional values.
When we zoom to x axis it actually stretches the viewport vertically and compresses horizontally. vice versa for y
for example, in viewport there is object which is horizontally too long so we can't see it in viewport fully from closely. so, scaling viewport non proportionally, we can compress object horizontally in viewport to view it closely without modifying actual scaling of object

OK, I see I think. I don't think it is possible even with the python API. or you'd have to implement your own gpu shaders to draw on top of the viewport

okay, thanks...

aLternaitvrly you can scale objects in object mode and revert back the scale afterwards
